# Need to insert node while processing html through XSLT

Tags: xslt

I am converting html to xml using XSLT 1.0. Here is my input

```
<table>
<tr id=1>
   <td rowspan=2>
   <td>
</tr>
<tr id=2>
   <td>   
</tr>
</table>
```

This is normal rowspan code in html.
If I am having attribute rowspan in td(id=1),I have to create a new element td in front of already existing td in tr(id=2).The number of new element td in consecutive tr depends on rowspan value.

How to do it in xsl template (or) any post process after xslt conversion ..please help me..Thanks in advance..

I will make it more clear..

The table is 3 *3. consider the first column in each row is merged.so my input html looks like this

```
<table>
<tr id="1">
    <td  rowspan="3">
         </p>
    </td>
   <td>
      </p>
   </td>
   <td>
      </p>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr id="2">
    <td>
         </p>
   </td>
   <td>
         </p>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr id="3">
   <td> 
         </p>
   </td>
   <td>
         </p>
   </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The  tr with id=2 & 3 has two td,means that the first column is merged with first tr-->td which has rowspan value as 3(that is 3 row including the current row cell is merged). my result should be

```
<w:tbl> <!-- represents table -->
<w:tr> <!-- represents table tr-->
  <w:tc>   <!-- represents table td-->
     <w:tcPr>  <!-- represents td style-->
         <w:vMerge w:val="restart"/> <!-- added due to having rowspan attribute-->
      </w:tcPr>
       <w:p/>
  </w:tc>
  <w:tc>
       <w:p/>
  </w:tc>
  <w:tc>
       <w:p/>
  </w:tc>
</w:tr>
<w:tr>
    <w:tc>  <!-- have to add this node in addition-->
          <w:tcPr>  
              <w:vMerge/>
          </w:tcPr>           
          <w:p/>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc> 
         <w:p/>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
         <w:p/>
    </w:tc>
<w:tr>
<w:tr>
    <w:tc>  <!-- have to add this node in addition-->
          <w:tcPr>  
              <w:vMerge/>
          </w:tcPr>           
          <w:p/>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
          <w:p/>
     </w:tc>
     <w:tc>
          <w:p/>
     </w:tc>
<w:tr>
</w:tbl>
```

Comment: @vignesh - Is the `rowspan` only on the first row? Or should each row simply look at its previous row for a `rowspan` value?

Comment: Can you post the desired output for the above input?

Comment: FYI in XSLT 1.0, the input needs to be well-formed XML. So I'm assuming the above input would be modified so that `<td>` tags are closed, attribute values are quoted, etc. Also, maybe above where you say "in td(id=1)" you mean "in *tr*(id=1)"? Or maybe the id=1 in your sample code should be on the td instead of the tr?

Comment: The problem you're posing is an interesting one, and a general (complete) XSLT solution is challenging. I'm curious though, whether this is really what you need to do. Why do you have to put new td's into the output table below rowspan cells?

Comment: @vignesh: As @LarsH suggest, table "normalization" is one of the most complex algorithm. But you didn't provide a desired output, making your question unclear about the real goal. And this is not the first question with such fault...

Comment: <table>
<tr id="1">
   <td rowspan="3">
   <td>
</tr>
<tr id=2>
   <td>   
</tr>
</table>

Comment: Ah! See? Now it's clear: you want table normalization... This algorithm is complex, really complex **in any language**. Consider `<table> <tr> <td rowspan="2"/> <td/> <td rowspan="2"/> </tr> <tr> <td/> </tr> </table>` just for start... See Andrew Welch's code at http://andrewjwelch.com/code/xslt/table/table-normalization.html

Comment: And the XSLT 1.0 with extensions (they could be removed using text format for `@rowspan` counters) posted earlier in [Dave Pawson's FAQ](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N7450.html#d10395e763)

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:** My latest approach is to count the total number of cells required based of the number of cells in the first row and their `rowspan` values. So, this input:

```
<table>
<tr id="1">
   <td rowspan="3"/>
   <td rowspan="2"/>
   <td/>
</tr>
<tr id="2">
   <td/>   
</tr>
<tr id="3">
   <td rowspan="2"/>
   <td/>   
</tr>
</table>
```

Should result in this output:

```
<table>
<tr id="1">
   <td rowspan="3"/>
   <td rowspan="2"/>
   <td/>
</tr>
<tr id="2">
   <td/><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/>   
</tr>
<tr id="3">
   <td/><td/><td/><td rowspan="2"/>
   <td/>   
</tr>
</table>
```

That is, each row should account for 6 cells (based on what was seen in the first row). This is a lot more flexible than my first attempt.

**Note:** It's not clear exactlty what the OP's desired output is, but you could save yourself a lot of trouble by simply outputting one new cell with the appropriate `rowspan` value, instead of multiple new cells.

Here's the stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:variable name="rowspan">
        <xsl:call-template name="sum">
            <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="/table/tr[1]/td" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="tr[position() &gt; 1]/td[1]">
        <xsl:variable name="currcount">
            <xsl:call-template name="sum">
                <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="../td" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="needed" select="$rowspan - $currcount" />
        <xsl:if test="$needed &gt; 0">
            <xsl:call-template name="loop">
                <xsl:with-param name="i">0</xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name="count">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$needed" />
                </xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="loop">
        <xsl:param name="i" />
        <xsl:param name="count" />
        <td />
        <xsl:if test="$i &lt; $count - 1">
            <xsl:call-template name="loop">
                <xsl:with-param name="i">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$i + 1" />
                </xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name="count">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$count" />
                </xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- modified version of @Tomalak's code in question 1333558 -->
    <xsl:template name="sum">
        <xsl:param name="nodes" />
        <xsl:param name="sum" select="0" />
        <xsl:variable name="curr" select="$nodes[1]" />
        <!-- if we have a node, calculate & recurse -->
        <xsl:if test="$curr">
            <xsl:variable name="runningsum">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$curr[@rowspan]">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$sum + $curr/@rowspan" />
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$sum + 1" />
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:call-template name="sum">
                <xsl:with-param name="nodes" 
                                select="$nodes[position() &gt; 1]" />
                <xsl:with-param name="sum" select="$runningsum" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
        <!-- if we don't have a node (last recursive step), return sum -->
        <xsl:if test="not($curr)">
            <xsl:value-of select="$sum" />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I hope someone comes along with a far shorter and more elegant solution.

Comment: Do note that `@rowspan` are expantions on row axis, not column axis.

Comment: @Alejandro - Good point. I'm sure `colspan` was meant. I didn't even notice.